# Why was this question protected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, protected-questions

A [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24829/420) recently hit the Hot Network Questions list.

I noticed that it was recently protected.

The normal reasons for protecting a question are to stop an influx of low-quality answers or non-answers posted as answers, yet I only see one deleted answer (which was deleted for being a non-answer).

Was the question protected because of that one answer?  If so, was that perhaps premature?  Content hitting the HNQ list is a great way to reach new users, even if the vast majority post once and never return.

[As I mentioned before](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/647/420), I feel that we should be fairly conservative in our use of protecting questions, particularly HNQ list questions, but it's entirely possible I missed something (deleted comments, etc.) that would merit moderator intervention, so asking here seemed the appropriate course.

Comment: Also note that all those users won't be able to answer it _at all_ ☹

Comment: The question was not protected because of low-quality answers. My reason for protecting it was because of a number of flagged comments in quick succession by low-rep users, which protecting helps to stem. Hmm. Maybe I should have waited? I often try to manage "iffy" comments by moving them to chat, but these were flagged as offensive (and I agreed.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thanks for responding.  I'm rusty, but I didn't think protecting stopped comments?

Comment: If it does, though, that's certainly a good reason to protect the question.

Comment: OK, I was in error. Lifted. TIL. Thanks for bringing that up. @Ángel - my apologies. :(

Comment: No problem, @anongoodnurse ☺